# Chance one square is queen's move away from another

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Here is a question from my probability book:

> Two squares are chosen at random on a chessboard: What is the chance that one is a queen's move from the other?

Here's what I did: I got$${{4((7 + 15) + (9 + 15) + (11 + 15) + (13 + 15)) + 8((7 + 15) + (9 + 15) + (11 + 15)) + 8((7 + 15) + (9 + 15)) + 8(7 + 15)}\over{64(63)}} = {{95}\over{252}}.$$However, the answer at the back of my book is ${{13}\over{36}}$, which equals ${{91}\over{252}}$, which is only ${4\over{252}}$ less than what I get. So I must be overcounting ${4\over{252}}$ somewhere. Where did I overcount or mess up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given one piece placement, there are 14 other squares, not 15, that are a rook move away.